# TCPDF Multicell combine columns

Tags: javascript, php, pdf, moodle, tcpdf

I have in my `print.php`, using `TCPDF`, the 2 `Multicell` `tables`, which show me every `date` and every `cardriver`:

```
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 40, ''.$dates, 0, 'J', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, true);
$pdf->MultiCell(55, 40, ''.$cardriver, 0, 'J', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 0, true);
```

Now the `tables` are shown `next` to each other, but the text in `$cardriver` starts one line `beneath`:

```
+-----------------------------------+----------+--+
|               Dates               | Drivers  |  |
+-----------------------------------+----------+--+
| 24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00        |          |  |
| 7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00        | Driver 1 |  |
| 22. December 2021 09:00 - 10:00   | Driver 2 |  |
| This row is testing html entities | Driver 3 |  |
+-----------------------------------+----------+--+
```

Is there any fix?

Or is it possible to make `one` `table` with the data from the both `variables`, `alligned` like that:

```
+---------------------------------+---+
|              Dates              |   |
+---------------------------------+---+
| 24. May 2016 08:30 - 17:00      |   |
| Driver 1                        |   |
| 7. June 2016 08:30 - 17:00      |   |
| Driver 2                        |   |
| 22. December 2021 09:00 - 10:00 |   |
| Driver 2                        |   |
+---------------------------------+---+
```

I got the `data` into the `PDF` in another file from the following `javascript`:

```
var dates = $("div.carhireinfo_dates span.carhireinfodata").text();
var drivers = $("div.carhireinfo_drivers span.carhireinfodata").text();
```

Thanks for the help.

S.

Comment: According to the docs - http://www.tcpdf.org/doc/code/classTCPDF.html#aa81d4b585de305c054760ec983ed3ece in order to use  `valign` -> `$valign (string) Vertical alignment of text (requires $maxh = $h > 0). Possible values are: T: TOP M: middle B: bottom`. So you could try something like `$pdf->MultiCell(55, 40, ''.$cardriver, 0, 'J', 0, 0, '', '', true, 0, false, true, 40, 'T');`

Comment: I tried it, it won't work, here the problem is that one empty line in the text, which is added to the drivers. Thatswhy I will preffer to solve it with the one table for the both variables.

Comment: Since your data is in different vars, `$dates` & `$cardriver`, you will need to merge them. Once way would be to explode them into arrays, and combine them together in order of the array keys.

Comment: I tried it like this, but it shows me `preg_match_all() expects parameter 2 to be string, array given in` Here is the code I use `$cardriver = explode('\n', $cardriver);
$dates = explode('\n', $dates);
$combined = array_combine($cardriver, $dates);



foreach($combined as $driver => $date){
   $pdf->writeHTML($combined, true, false, true, false, '');
}`
The strings come out like this `30. Dezember 2015 09:00 - 10:00 24. Januar 2016 09:00 - 10:00 24. Februar 2016 09:00 - 10:00 24. Dezember 2016 09:00 - 10:00
`